# How to pass the one controller value of first.js file into another controller of second.js file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

> Hi im new to angularjs, Here i do have two js files and i need to pass
>   the the value in one js file to another js file even in
>   angularjs.since i need to display the navbar accoding to user and
>   admin login.

```
<form name="vm.loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="vm.login(vm.getUser);">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <input id="login-username" type="email" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email" data-ng-model="vm.getUser.Username" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 input-group margin-top-20">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" data-ng-model="vm.getUser.Password" required value="admin">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 margin-top-20">
                            <span class="pull-left">
                                <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                            </span>
                            <span class="pull-right">
                                <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 margin-top-20">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                                Login
                                <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" ng-show="vm.login.progress"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

> logincrl.js

```
login.controller("loginCtrl", ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$location', 'Flash', 'apiService', '$http',
    function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $location, Flash, apiService, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        $scope.title="Test";
        vm.login = function(data) {
            vm.login.progress=true;
            var url = "http://52.9.55.95:91/api/Login/ValidateUser?username=" + $scope.vm.getUser.Username + "&password=" + $scope.vm.getUser.Password;
            $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

           $scope.RoleCode == data.RoleCode;

      vm.login.progress=false;
      $state.go('app.dashboard');

    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        vm.login.progress=false;
      swal({   title: "Warning!",   text: "Invalid User Credentials!",   type: "warning",   confirmButtonText: "OK" }); 

    });

        }


    }
]);
```

> in this js file i need to pass the value like $scope.role =
>   data.RoleCode to another js file.

```
appctrl.js

app.controller("appCtrl", ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$location', 'Flash', 'appSettings',
function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $location, Flash, appSettings) {

if($scope.Rolecode == 01){
vm.menuItems = [
        // {
        //     title: "Dashboard",
        //     icon: "dashboard",
        //     state: "dashboard"
        // },
        {
            title: "Employees",
            icon: "users",
            state: "employees"
        },
        {
            title: "Customers",
            icon: "users",
            state: "customers"
        },
}else(Rolecode=02){
vm.menuItems = [ {
            title: "Customers",
            icon: "users",
            state: "customers"
        },
]}
]}]);
```

> NOTE: According to the login i need to display the menu bar, RoleCode =
>   01 means Admin once should display and Rolecode = 02 means user once
>   display please let me know how to pass the value and please make an
>   fiddle and give it would very easy to understand for me,

```
app.html
        <section class="sidebar">
            <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
            <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li class="treeview" ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="vm.sideBar();" data-ng-repeat="menu in vm.menuItems">
                    <a ui-sref="app.{{menu.state}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-{{menu.icon}}"></i> <span>{{menu.title}}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

> can any one help out how to pass the value. in one js to another js
>   file different controller and different files

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store Role value , you can use $rootScope.Role = data.RoleCode and then inject $rootScope to another controller and get $rootScope.Role.
OR you can use $emit and $broadcast for passing values between controllers , there are lots of material available on google for that.

Comment: but i do have two js files tat is the problem if same file and different controller means we can do it

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with `services` here, you can create a service and inject the service into each controller then you can work with role and you can access this role in every page, its reusable in every controller

Comment: can u please share the code if u dont mind please, since i tried with localstorage, rootscope, also it is not coming

Comment: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/angularjs-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial ref here, it has different ways to do it

Comment: this is even simpler http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/12/09/authentication-made-simple-in-single-page-angularjs-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use AngularJs service to pass values from one controller to another. Assume you have firstCtrl, secondCtrl and yourService in different js files, then you have to add references to those files in index.html. I included a sample code. Hope your will able to get an idea from it.

**index.html**

```
  <script src="firstCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="secondCtrl.js "></script>
  <script src="yourService.js"></script>
```

**Controllers and Service**

```js
/* Assume firstCtrl in seperate js file */
angular.module('yourAppName').controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, yourService) {
  /*Set  data to service*/
  yourService.data = $scope.data;
});

/*End firstCtrl*/

/* Assume secondCtrl in seperate js file */
angular.module('yourAppName').controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, yourService) {
  /*Get data from service*/
  var data = yourService.data;
});

/*End secondCtrl*/

/* Assume yourService in seperate js file */
angular.module('yourAppName').factory('yourService', function() {
  var data = null;
  return {
    data: data
  }
});
/*End yourService*/
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a `service` to set and get the data between the `controllers` and then `inject` that service in the controller function where we want to use it.

**Service :**

```
app.service('setGetData', function() {
  var data = '';
    getData: function() { return data; },
    setData: function(requestData) { data = requestData; }
});
```

**Controllers :**

**loginctrl.js**

```
app.controller('loginctrl', ['setGetData',function(setGetData) {

  // To set the data from the one controller
  $scope.RoleCode == data.RoleCode;  
  setGetData.setData($scope.RoleCode);

}]);
```

**appctrl.js**

```
app.controller('appctrl', ['setGetData',function(setGetData) {

  // To get the data from the another controller  
  var res = setGetData.getData();
  console.log(res);

}]);
```

Here, we can see that `loginctrl` is used for setting the data and `appctrl` is used for getting the data. So, we can share the data from one controller to another controller like this.